# Difference between multilple sql like statements vs single like any

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-like

I wanted to ask from a code efficiency / CPU USAGE perspective whether it is better to use like or like any in sql.

I often scan multiple strings (often thousands) and this leads to high cpu usage unfortunately...

I often found the below approach convenient but it makes my statements really long and I assume unfriendly to the database...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE
COLUMN 1 LIKE ('%WORD1%') OR 
COLUMN 1 LIKE ('%WORD2%') OR 
COLUMN 1 LIKE ('%WORD3%')
ETC.
```

Would using a LIKE ANY ('%WORD1%', '%WORD2%') be more efficient healthier for the sql database or are there other better alternatives?

Comment: why didn't you test it, on your system?

Comment: Your example show different columns, which can't be rewritten suing LIKA ANY. Otherwise it's exactly the same, LIKE ANY is reqritten to ORed LIKEs, check Exxplain. You might try a RegEx with alternation: `WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '(WORD1|WORD2|WORD3)') > ''`